# fs.readFile is not a function MQTT certificates

Tags: javascript, mqtt, fs

I am trying to read certifificates to access my Mqtt broker via js and node.js. However I get the following error : fs.readFile is not a function.

I noticed that fs seems deprecated in npm packages, so I tried using graceful-fs and fs-extra but it led me to similar errors. I also tried changing require to import but it didn't change anything.

Here is my code:

```
import Mqtt from 'mqtt';
const fs = require('fs');
var caFile = fs.readFile("myCApath")
var certFile = fs.readFile("myCERTpath")
var keyFile = fs.readFile("myKEYpath")
const client = Mqtt.connect({host: 'adress', port:'1884', username:'username',password:'passwd', ca: caFile});
```

And here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.0.9",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "element-ui": "^2.11.1",
    "leaflet": "^1.5.1",
    "mqtt": "^3.0.0",
    "start": "^5.1.0",
    "vue": "^2.6.10",
    "vue-router": "^3.1.2",
    "vuex": "^3.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^3.10.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^3.10.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^3.10.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-airbnb": "^4.0.1",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.2",
    "babel-plugin-component": "^1.1.1",
    "eslint": "^6.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^5.2.3",
    "vue-cli-plugin-element": "^1.0.1",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "@vue/airbnb"
    ],
    "rules": {
      "import/extensions": [
        "error",
        "always",
        {
          "js": "never",
          "vue": "never"
        }
      ],
      "no-param-reassign": [
        "error",
        {
          "props": true,
          "ignorePropertyModificationsFor": [
            "state",
            "acc",
            "e",
            "s"
          ]
        }
      ],
      "max-len": [
        "off"
      ],
      "vue/no-unused-vars": [
        "off"
      ]
    },
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    }
  },
  "postcss": {
    "plugins": {
      "autoprefixer": {}
    }
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not ie <= 8"
  ]
}
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Where exactly is that code running? Is the error coming from the NodeJS app or from the browser side?

Comment: I run this code in a spring boot app, and then the error comes up in the browser consolen the browser returns a blank page

Comment: OK, you can't access files from the browser (you also can't set the certificates for the MQTT client in the browser, because all the certificate handling is done by the browser for WebSocket connection)

Comment: Oh alright, thank you, so do you know how I can make my frontend and mqtt communicate ?

Comment: That is a totally different question and there is no where near enough detail in your question to answer properly. But MQTT over Websockets works just fine, but the browser needs to trust an CAs used to sign certificates upfront.

Comment: Alright I will look up to get certificates in the browser, thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closing my own question answered in comments by [hardillb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/504554/hardillb):

"you can't access files from the browser (you also can't set the certificates for the MQTT client in the browser, because all the certificate handling is done by the browser for WebSocket connection)"

Answer (score 0):

`fs.readFile` needs 3 parameters. **fs.readFile('fileName', 'utf8', function)** here the function will be callback function to handle errors or get the required data.
You can try this :-

```
var caFile = fs.readFile('myCApath.txt', 'utf8', function(err, data){
    if(err){
       console.log(err);
    }else{      
      return data; 
    }
});
```

If you want to ignore the second parameter then you can ignore, but I recommend to use the `encoding`.

Edited -
Or you can try using `fs.readFileSync( path, options )`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it still returns the same error :/

Answer (score 0):

`fs.readFile` is asynchronous function it means you need try to connect in callback function. Else the variable `caFile`, `certFile` and `keyFile` program reads as `undefined`

You can use `Promise` like this

```
import Mqtt from 'mqtt';
const fs = require('fs')

const read = (path, type) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  fs.readFile(path, type, (err, file) => {
    if (err) reject(err)
    resolve(file)
  })
})

Promise.all([read('myCApath', 'utf8'), read('myCERTpath', 'utf8'), read('myKEYpath', 'utf8')]).then((arr) => {
  const client = Mqtt.connect({host: 'adress', port:'1884', username:'username',password:'passwd', ca: arr[0]});
});
```

Another way use callback

```
import Mqtt from 'mqtt';
const fs = require('fs');

var caFile = fs.readFile("myCApath", "utf-8", function() {
  var certFile = fs.readFile("myCERTpath", "utf-8", function() {
    var keyFile = fs.readFile("myKEYpath", "utf-8", function() {
      const client = Mqtt.connect({host: 'adress', port:'1884', username:'username',password:'passwd', ca: caFile});
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but both techniques still return the same error :/

Comment: Can you please type in the command line `node -v` and tell me which version you have

Comment: No problem, i have version v16.11.1

Comment: Do you have file `package.json` or `webpack.config.js` ? Can you provide the content of these files

Comment: I will add my package.json to the main question, I also have a package-lock.json, should I show it too ?

Comment: No, only `package.json`

Comment: Try to remove this property temporary: `"import/extensions": [
        "error",
        "always",
        {
          "js": "never",
          "vue": "never"
        }
      ]` If it doesn't work, return this code back

Comment: I removed it but I still have the error, I put it back.

Comment: Do you have the file `.eslintrc` ? Maybe in this file are some restrictions .

Comment: I don't have such file, but according to hardillb, the problem comes from the fact that I try to access a certificate file via the browser. Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0):

Use `fs.readFileSync(path)` [docs](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fsreadfilesyncpath-options)

```
import Mqtt from 'mqtt';
const fs = require('fs');
var caFile = fs.readFileSync("myCApath")
var certFile = fs.readFileSync("myCERTpath")
var keyFile = fs.readFileSync("myKEYpath")
const client = Mqtt.connect({host: 'adress', port:'1884', username:'username',password:'passwd', ca: caFile});
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer, however the error became 'fs.readFileSync is not a function' :/

Comment: What version of NodeJS are you using?

Comment: I am using node v16.11.1

Comment: `fs` is a core module and `fs.readFileSync()` has been included since v0.1.8. [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70034272/edit) the question to include the package.json for your project. (I'm assuming you have tried to install a version of the `fs` node, which you should not need to do)

Comment: I just edited the question and included package.json, I can't find fs in node_modules